# I am getting this error "Could not get constructor for org.hibernate.persister.entity.SingleTableEntityPersister"?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, hibernate, spring-mvc

I am trying to make a spring-hibernate application but I am getting this error

`Request processing failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.MappingException: Could not get constructor for org.hibernate.persister.entity.SingleTableEntityPersister`

I know this error comes when it tries to find getters and setters and couldn't get them. But i checked my getters and setters properly they are correct.

Please help me with this.

My Structure is like this

[image]

And code is

1. Employee.java

```
package com.wipro.config;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table(name="empdata")
public class Employee {
    
    @Id
    private String empname;
    @Column(name="designation",length=15)
    private String designation;
    @Column(name="email",length=25)
    private String email;
    
    public String getEmpname() {
        return empname;
    }
    public void setEmpname(String empname) {
        this.empname = empname;
    }
    public String getDesignation() {
        return designation;
    }
    public void setDesignation(String designation) {
        this.designation = designation;
    }
    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }
    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }
    
    
    
}
```

2. EmployeeDao.java

```
package com.wipro.config;

import java.io.File;

import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.Transaction;
import org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration;

public class EmployeeDao {

    private SessionFactory factory;
    private Session session;
    private Transaction t;
    
    public EmployeeDao() {
        
    }
    
    public void saveData(Employee e) {
        
        factory =new Configuration().configure(new File("F:/Wipro teachings/springg/crud/src/main/java/com/wipro/config/hibernate.cfg.xml")).buildSessionFactory();
            session=factory.openSession();
            t=session.beginTransaction();
            session.save(e);
            t.commit();
        
    }

}
```

3. ControllerDemo.java

```
package com.wipro.controller;

import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ModelAttribute;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;

import com.wipro.config.Employee;
import com.wipro.config.EmployeeDao;

@Controller
public class ControllerDemo {
    private ApplicationContext conn;
    
    public ControllerDemo() {
        
    }
    @RequestMapping("/home")
    public String view1() {
        return "home";
    }
    
    @RequestMapping("/register")
    public String view2(Model m) {
        conn=new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("ApplicationContext.xml");
        Employee emp=conn.getBean("info",Employee.class);
        m.addAttribute("bean",emp);
        return "register";
    }
    
    @RequestMapping("/store")
    public String view3(@ModelAttribute("bean") Employee e,Model m) {
        conn=new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("ApplicationContext.xml");
        EmployeeDao obj=conn.getBean("dao",EmployeeDao.class);
        obj.saveData(e);
        m.addAttribute("msg","Record Inserted Successfully");
        return "register";
    }
    
}
```

4. hibernate.cfg.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
        "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
        "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.password">Musu</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:oracle:thin:@Localhost:1521:orcl</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.username">sys as sysdba</property>
        <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle8iDialect</property>
        <property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle8iDialect</property> 
        <property name="hbm2ddl.auto">update</property>
        <property name="hibernate.show_sql">true</property>  
    
    <mapping class="com.wipro.config.Employee"/>
    
    
    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

5. ApplicationContext.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<beans  
    xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"  
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"  
    xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"  
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans  
               http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd">
               
   
<bean id="info" class="com.wipro.config.Employee"></bean>
 
 <bean id="dao" class="com.wipro.config.EmployeeDao"></bean>              
</beans>
```

6. home.jsp

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
<a href="register">Register</a>
</body>
</html>
```

7. register.jsp

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
    <%@taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" prefix="form" %>
    <%@page isELIgnored="false" %>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Register Page</h1>
    <form:form action="store" method="post" modelAttribute="bean">
        Enter name=<form:input path="empname"/><br><br>
        Enter designation=<form:input path="designation"/><br><br>
        Enter email=<form:input path="email"/><br><br>  
    <input type="submit" value="register">
    </form:form>
    <br>
    <h2>${msg}</h2>
    
</body>
</html>
```

8. spring-servlet.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"  
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"   
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"  
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"  
    xsi:schemaLocation="  
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans  
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd  
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context  
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd  
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc  
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd"> 
        
        <context:component-scan base-package="com.wipro"></context:component-scan>
        <mvc:annotation-driven></mvc:annotation-driven>
        <bean id="vr" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
            <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/"></property>
            <property name="suffix" value=".jsp"></property>
        </bean>
        
        </beans>
```

10. web.xml

```
<!DOCTYPE web-app PUBLIC
 "-//Sun Microsystems, Inc.//DTD Web Application 2.3//EN"
 "http://java.sun.com/dtd/web-app_2_3.dtd" >

<web-app>
  <display-name>Archetype Created Web Application</display-name>

    <servlet>
    <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class> org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
    
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

11. index.jsp

```
<html>
<body>
<h2>Hello World!</h2>
<a href="home">Home</a>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please add no args default constructor to your entity Employee and see what happens.  _public Employee(){}_

Comment: Tried that still the same error.

Comment: This error is pretty broad. Internet shows users who had this error while moving to Java 11 from 9  or updating hibernate version or missing javassist in pom.xml. What have you tried  so far? What is Java version , ahve you tried to switch hibernate version or add javassist  to pom.xml ?

Comment: You ar eprobably mixing jars from different versions of Hibernate which you shouldn't do. That being said your code is also flawed, 1. you should use spring to manage the Hibernate Session Factory and 2. don't create an application context to get beans, eventually you will run out of memory and 3. that code isn't thread safe.

Comment: You were right. The problem was with versions in the pom.xml file. I changed the file and finally got the output. Thank you @DanyloGurianov and  M. Deinum for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this issue by adding a no argument constractor. If you are using Lombok, you only need to add @NoArgsConstructor annotation:

```
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Getter
@ToString
@EqualsAndHashCode
public class User {
    private Long userId;
    private String shortName;
}
```